# Multiple Linear Regression and Orthogonal Distance

Tags: geometry, orthogonality, linear-regression

### Problem

The problem is to measure the Perpendicular Distance of a Retangular Shape.

[image: Problem]

Some edge points are taken from the shape and the data below is acquired:

```
+-----+-----+
|  x  |  y  |
+-----+-----+
| 192 |  52 |
|  69 |  89 |
| 204 |  89 |
|  80 | 126 |
| 216 | 126 |
|  91 | 163 |
| 227 | 163 |
| 102 | 200 |
| 239 | 200 |
| 113 | 237 |
| 250 | 237 |
| 124 | 274 |
| 261 | 274 |
| 135 | 311 |
| 272 | 311 |
| 146 | 348 |
| 284 | 348 |
+-----+-----+
```

The following points are seen:

[image: Points]

#### Linear Regression

I tried to make a linear regression so the `m` of y=mx+b would be the same, however, that's what i got:

[image: Linear Regression]

#### Question

How do i get to identify multiple lines and make a linear regression for each one, so that the width can be measured?

Is There another way?

The next step is to have 2 retangular shapes and try to calculate the width.

Comment: Another solution is to use RANSAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the points $(x_i,y_i)$ contain errors and that you want the "best" parallel lines, I should introduce another variable $t_i$ which would be $0$ for any point on one edge and $1$ for any point on the other edge.

Now, take all points together and perform the multilinear regression for the model
$$y=a+bx+ct$$ When done, select one point along $y=a+bx$ and compute its distance to the line $y=a+bx+c$.

The perpendicular distance will be $$d=\frac{|c|}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}$$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_between_two_straight_lines)).

**Edit**

Hoping no mistake, you data are then
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & t & y \\
 192 & 1 & 52 \\
 69 & 0 & 89 \\
 204 & 1 & 89 \\
 80 & 0 & 126 \\
 216 & 1 & 126 \\
 91 & 0 & 163 \\
 227 & 1 & 163 \\
 102 & 0 & 200 \\
 239 & 1 & 200 \\
 113 & 0 & 237 \\
 250 & 1 & 237 \\
 124 & 0 & 274 \\
 261 & 1 & 274 \\
 135 & 0 & 311 \\
 272 & 1 & 311 \\
 146 & 0 & 348 \\
 284 & 1 & 348
\end{array}
\right)$$ and the multilinear regression leads to 
$$y=-135.049+3.28883 \,x-448.788\, t$$ making $d\approx 130.6$